# Oj Algo concurrency

Tags: java, math, matrix, ojalgo

I develop a program using ojAlgo library for computing matrix exponential. It includes eigen value decomposition. **Does ojAlgo include multi-threaded algorithms ?** For example is it possible to attach more than one thread to the decomposition task to reduce decomposition time?

```
eigenvalue = Eigenvalue.PRIMITIVE.make(matrix);
eigenvalue.decompose(matrix); //matrix dimension (3000x3000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. If you look inside that factory method `Eigenvalue.PRIMITIVE.make(matrix);` you'll se that it switches implementation depending on matrix size. The implementation used for the larger matrices is multi-threaded. The only problem for you is that the single-threaded implementation is so efficient that the factory doesn't switch to multi-threading until the matrices are larger than 8192.

Do you know if the matrices are symmetric or not? If you do I would recommend you to use `Eigenvalue.PRIMITIVE.make(matrix, boolean);` instead of `Eigenvalue.PRIMITIVE.make(matrix);`. Otherwise the algorithm will check for symmetry with every call to `eigenvalue.decompose(matrix);`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the single threaded implementation is efficient for my matrix I will keep it.  Thank you for your recommendation, I know that my matrix is not symmetric, I will use the second approach with false.